# Reduced adverb clauses with IF and Passive voice

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, passive-voice

I want to reduce the adverb clause in this sentence:

> "If they were treated fairly, they wouldn't lose the game."

Which of the following sentences, if any, are correct?

1. If treated fairly, they wouldn't lose the game.
2. If being treated fairly, they wouldn't lose the game."

Comment: The best alternative would be your first or even, "Treated fairly they wouldn't lose the game". The second is awkward. (You don't need the comma, by the way.)